# Get a CSV to list to object in dart

Tags: flutter, csv, object, dart

I have a CSV file in dart / flutter that I download and read and convert it to list using the CSV flutter package which results in a `<List<List<Dynamic>>`

```
[[1,10:10,20:20,08:08],[2,01:05,01:10,19:24]...]
```

I for the key I want, which results in `List<Dynamic>` achieved using:

`_listData.indexWhere((element) => element.first == 2)` which will result in the value `1`

I thereafter want to reference these quite easily somewhere else in the program by calling something like

`myTimes.startTime` , `myTimes.lap1`,`myTimes.lap2`,`myTimes.lap3`,`myTimes.mlap3`

I was thinking something along the lines of how we create a class similar to
json model to map the values so they can be easily referenced.

How can I accomplish this easily stopping short of typing it all out?

I am open to arriving at the same result if there is a more efficient method out there...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by creating a model class with a factory constructor.

```
class MyTimes(){

MyTimes({required this.startTime});

final DateTime startTime;

factory MyTimes.fromRow(List<dynamic> row) => MyTimes(startTime: DateTime.parse(row.elementat(1))

}
```